# DB modelling - tables for unregistered members

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a conceptual DB model, and I want to include tables for handling unregistered members. I would like to save Name, Date of unregistration, and Phone, Email and maybe Address.

How is this usually done? Should I put everything in one table or should I use at least one more table for contact info and a type table?

Comment: How does the member become registered? Why not just have a flag for registered or not?

Comment: The amount of unregistered members is about half the table size. I'm optimizing for a new model. It's not a web app, it's a register for  house rental.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the table, you may want to have a separate table for unregistered members. The issue with having a separate table is with duplicate members (in case a member becomes re-registered). You could write a trigger that checks the other table. Otherwise, a simple flag that determines whether the member is registered or unregistered should do.

Comment: In this case It's necessary to move the parts of the member that should be kept, like the columns I described. But should one table do for all that data you think?

Comment: It's really difficult to suggest something with so little information.